# LG G2 not picking 3G and GSM Signals

Tags: mobile-network, lg, 4g

I just bought an LG G2 32GB Version from China. The problem is it does not pick up any network connection, it keeps saying Searching for service. I just noticed the box is written 100%LTE. Is there any way to unlock it to recieve 3G Signals. Help!

Comment: In which country do you want to use the phone? Your question kind of suggests that you have bought in in china but want to use it in another country.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently i bought a phone locked to sprint network, i found a sweet guide on how to unlock it on another forum. Thanks though. Not sure if im allowed to post links to other forums here so PM me if you need the link. Thanks